# Forge ARKit Get Unity Status 501 Not Implemented

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

I was trying the Forge ARKit API (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0#/info) and I was able to load a revit model in Unity through the asset (http://forgetoolkit.com/#/unityPackage). Then I saw that the API has an url to download a model as UnityPackage (https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/cyrillef/forge-ar_kit/2.0.0#/ARKit/get_unity), but unfortunately I get a 501 status Not Implemented.

I'm doing a GET request to "https://developer-api-beta.autodesk.io/modelderivative/v2/arkit/{{urn}}/unity" with the Authorization token and the same urn base64url I used for the other urls.

Comment: As the HTTP error code says, this endpoint is not yet implemented - the Swagger definition says what I intent to develop, but the project is still in research mode while it will soon move to a production service and you can expect this endpoint to be present.

Comment: @cyrille oh ok. I'm pretty new to APIs so I wasn't sure about that. I'll keep on touch for any news because that endpoint would be extremely helpful to me.